# Delete files which doesn't present in xml list

Tags: java, xml, download, md5, etag

I need some help to finish a function in a java application.

This function is used to download files, where are listed in a xml file located at the root of the download base URL. It compares files etags with already downloaded files etags, and update. But obsolete files still in local folder, and that creates a conflict problem.

Here is the code :

```
    private Set<Downloadable> getInternetFiles(Proxy proxy, File baseDirectory) {
    Set<Downloadable> result = new HashSet<Downloadable>();
    try
    {
        URL resourceUrl = new URL(UrlClass.DOWNLOAD_URL);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(resourceUrl.openStream());
        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Contents");

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeLst.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == 1) {
                Element element = (Element)node;
                String key = element.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                String etag = element.getElementsByTagName("ETag") != null ? element.getElementsByTagName("ETag").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue() : "-";
                long size = Long.parseLong(element.getElementsByTagName("Size").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                if (size > 0L) {
                    File file = new File(baseDirectory, "/" + key);
                    if (etag.length() > 1) {
                        etag = Downloadable.getEtag(etag);
                        if ((file.isFile()) && (file.length() == size)) {
                            String localMd5 = Downloadable.getMD5(file);
                            if (localMd5.equals(etag)) continue;
                        }
                    }
                    Downloadable downloadable = new Downloadable(proxy, new URL(UrlClass.DOWNLOAD_URL + key), file, false);
                    downloadable.setExpectedSize(size);
                    result.add(downloadable);
                }
            }
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long delta = end - start;
        Launcher.getInstance().println("Time to compare : " + delta / 1000000L + " ms ");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Launcher.getInstance().println("Couldn't download files", ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I really need it to continue my project but don't know how I can implement the delete method.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried methods like 'Node.removeChild(child)' ?? What else have you tried ?

Comment: I didn't try it and nothing more because I don't really know where i could implement it. I thought about create one array fore each side and compare values.